# Help calculating average per day

Tags: mysql

The `daily_average` column is always returning zero.  The default timestamp values are for the past week.  Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here in getting the average order value per day?

```
SELECT
    SUM(price+shipping_price) AS total_sales,
    COUNT(id) AS total_orders,
    AVG(price+shipping_price) AS order_total_average,
    (SELECT
            SUM(quantity)
        FROM `order_product`
        INNER JOIN `order` ON (
            `order`.id = order_product.order_id AND
            `order`.created >= '.$startTimestamp.' AND
            `order`.created <= '.$endTimestamp.' AND
            `order`.type_id = '.$type->getId().' AND
            `order`.fraud = 0
        )
    ) as total_units,
    SUM(price+shipping_price)/DATEDIFF('.$endTimestamp.', '.$startTimestamp.') as daily_average
FROM `order`
WHERE created >= '.$startTimestamp.' AND
created <= '.$endTimestamp.' AND
fraud = 0 AND
type_id = '.$type->getId().'
```

Comment: What are startTimestamp and endTimestamp?  Time since epoch?  Formatted dates?  If formatted, how?  DATEDIFF takes dates as opposed to timestamps.  FROM_UNIXTIME would help if they are time since epoch.

Answer (score 0):

You're using aggregate functions ([SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum), [COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count), [AVG](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)) without an aggregate command (group by).  I think your SQL is more complicated than it needs to be (no need for the inner select).

Here's a SQL command that should work (hard to test without test data ;))

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(id) total_orders,
  SUM(finalprice) total_sales,
  AVG(finalprice) order_average,
  SUM(units) total_units,
  SUM(finalprice)/DATEDIFF('.$endTimestamp.', '.$startTimestamp.') daily_average
FROM (
  SELECT
    o.id id,
    o.price+o.shipping_price finalprice,
    SUM(p.quantity) units
  FROM order o INNER JOIN order_product p ON p.order_id=o.id
  WHERE o.created>='.$startTimestamp.' 
    AND o.created<='.$endTimestamp.'
    AND o.fraud=0
    AND o.type_id='.$type->getId().'
  GROUP BY p.order_id
) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does casting one of the elements in the division work for you?

```
SELECT
    SUM(price+shipping_price) AS total_sales,
    COUNT(id) AS total_orders,
    AVG(price+shipping_price) AS order_total_average,
    (SELECT
        SUM(quantity)
        FROM `order_product`
        INNER JOIN `order` ON (
        `order`.id = order_product.order_id AND
        `order`.created >= '.$startTimestamp.' AND
        `order`.created <= '.$endTimestamp.' AND
        `order`.type_id = '.$type->getId().' AND
        `order`.fraud = 0
        )
    ) as total_units,
    CAST(SUM(price+shipping_price) AS float)/DATEDIFF('.$endTimestamp.', '.$startTimestamp.') as daily_average
FROM `order`
WHERE created >= '.$startTimestamp.' AND
created <= '.$endTimestamp.' AND
fraud = 0 AND
type_id = '.$type->getId().'
```